# Estimates of the Frobenius norm of commutator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, norms

Let $A,B$ be two unitary matrices in $U(n)$, and $\|\cdot\|_{F}$ denote the Frobenius norm (or Hilbert Schmidt norm on the finite dimensional $M_n(\mathbb{C})$). I am looking for estimates of the commutator of $A$ and $B$ in terms of $\|AB-BA\|_{F}$. Now $\|A\|_{F}=\|B\|_{F}=\sqrt{n}$, so the submultiplicative estimates (as in Bottcher-Wenzel etc. where $\|AB-BA\|_{F}\le\sqrt2\|A\|_F\|B\|_F$) are not particularly useful when $A,B$ are unitary.

Let's instead deal with $\|A-I\|_{F}$ and $\|B-I\|_{F}$. In a sense, this is like dealing with the corresponding norms on the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ of $U(n)$ instead.

When both $\|A-I\|_{F}$ and $\|B-I\|_{F}$ are small, say smaller than $\varepsilon$ for  $1>\varepsilon>0$, then from submultiplicativity, we have  $\|AB-BA\|_{F}< 2\varepsilon^2$. Thus  $\|AB-BA\|_{F}$ is asymptotically smaller than $\|A-I\|_{F}$ and $\|B-I\|_{F}$ when $A$ and $B$ lie in a small ball around the identity.

But this submultiplicativity alone doesn't help us when $\|A-I\|_F$ and $\|B-I\|_F$ are larger than 1 (per se, they could be as large as $O(\sqrt{n})$ ). This leads to the question of whether even in larger balls around the identity, does the commutator shrink significantly?
So my question is as follows:

> Suppose we know that $\|A-I\|_F$ and $\|B-I\|_F$ are $o(\sqrt{n})$ (that is, asymptotically not as large as possible). Then what can we say about $\|AB-BA\|_{F}$? Is it still asymptotically strictly smaller than the norms of $\|A-I\|_F$ and $\|B-I\|_F$? I'd hope for some small commutator at least statistically with some sharp estimates.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what exactly you mean by "asymptotically strictly smaller". But you can just take two matrices $C,D\in U(2)$ that don't commute and then build $A, B$ as orthogonal sums of these. If you use $N\gg 1$ such summands, then $A, B, [A,B]$ will all have Hilbert-Schmidt norm $\simeq \sqrt{N}$. (So the commutator is not smaller.)

Comment: Hi @Christian Remling, what would be the norms of $A-I$ and $B-I$ in your setting? Also, there is a result of Bottcher-Wenzel which roughly says that if you sample over two matrices $A$ and $B$ of norm $1$, then the expected value of norm of $[A,B]$ is $O(1/n)$ (and variance $O(1/n^4)$. So in this general setting, at least in a random sense, the commutator shrinks significantly. I'm curious if something like that can hold here too.

Comment: All norms (of $A-1,B-1, [A,B]$) equal $cN^{1/2}$, with different $c$'s.

Comment: @Christian Remling: Yeah, thats the thing. If we work over the whole of U(n), where $\|A-I\|$ and $\|B-I\|$ could be as bad as $2\sqrt{n}$, then their commutator too could have norm $\|[A,B]\|$ as large as $O(\sqrt{n})$. This is kind of the trivial case with no useful info. But I suspect that if we restrict to asymptotically smaller $\|A-I\|$ and $\|B-I\|$, then $\|[A,B]\|$ shrinks pretty rapidly. It is known to shrink in a small balls around the identity, my question is whether it shrinks even for larger balls.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my example. My $N$ is not necessarily your $n$; rather, we can take any $N\le n$. So this refutes the scenario you were hoping for in your previous comment.